# How do I render an array from my /container into /component expo

Tags: reactjs, arrays, react-native, expo, render

I need to take the data from an array in the container and print it into my component.
the thing is before I used FlatList with Card inside it, but I was told that in this View there was no need to do it, "just print it directly"

The thing is that when I try to read the data, all I get is "undefined". From the card everything was right.

This is the Component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Image, FlatList, RefreshControl, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { SimpleHeader, Layout, Button, View, Text } from '../../elements/index';

import { Card } from 'components/elements';
import { render } from 'react-native-web';

const OrdersDetailsComponent = ({ ordersdetails, navigation }) => {


    return (
        <Layout style={styles.wrapper}>


            <SimpleHeader
                style={styles.head}
                title={<Text style={styles.title}>{ordersdetails.nOrder}</Text>}
                onBackPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
            />

            <View style={styles.section}>
                <Text>Detalles del pedido</Text>
            </View>

            <View>

                <View>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>{ordersdetails.street}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>{ordersdetails.time}</Text>
                </View>
                <View>
                    <Image source={ordersdetails.map} style={styles.image}></Image>
                </View>

            </View>
            <View style={styles.section}>
                <Text>Contacto</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.sectionData}>
                <Text>Nombre </Text>
                <Text>teléfono</Text>
            </View>

            <View style={styles.section}>
                <Text>Asignado</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.sectionData}>
                <Text>Empleado(Celia)</Text>
            </View>
        </Layout>
    );
};



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    wrapper: {
        backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
        display: "flex",
        flex: 1,
    },
    tab: {
        margin: 20,
        justifyContent: "space-evenly"

    },
    head: {
        width: 400,
        display: "flex",
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: "pink",
    },
    scrollview: {
        alignContent: "flex-end",
        backgroundColor: "pink",
        display: "flex",
    },
    buttonContainer: {
        marginHorizontal: 20
    },
    button: {
        backgroundColor: "#000000",
        top: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 12 : 20,
        height: 60,
        marginBottom: 40,
        marginRight: 10,

    },


});
export default OrdersDetailsComponent;
```

This is the Container with its array:

```
import React from 'react'
import OrdersDetailsComponent from '../components/OrdersDetailsComponent';


const OrdersDetails = (props) => {


    // este array deberia de ser leido desde Orders? de ese modo al que se haga click es el que se muestra en OrdersDetailsComponent
    const ordersdetails = [{
        id: "1",
        nOrder: "Pedido N566",
        street: " C/ del Áncora, 6",
        time: 1630,
        tab: 'Recogidas',
        map: require('../../elements/assets/MapExample.png'),
        contact: [{
            name: "Celia Sánchez",
            phone: '+34 654 654 654',
        }],
         Asignado: "Lourdes Martín"
    },
]

    return (


        <OrdersDetailsComponent
            ordersdetails={ordersdetails}
            {...props} />

    )
}
export default OrdersDetails;
```

Comment: `ordersdetails` is an array in `OrdersDetails` but you treat it as an object in the `OrdersDetailsComponent`. If you know that the array `ordersdetails` always contain a single element use `ordersdetails={ordersdetails[0]}`. If you want to show multiple `OrdersDetailsComponents` for every element in the array, use a FlatList or use map.

Answer (score 0):

`ordersdetails` is an array but you are just trying to render it which react tree won't transpile.

You need to use [es6 map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in this case to extract variables. Below is an example.

```
{
  ordersdetails.map((details) => <SimpleHeader
    style={styles.head}
    title={<Text style={styles.title}>{ordersdetails.nOrder}</Text>}
    onBackPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
  />)
}
```